# Python - Fast reads from file system

Tags: python

I have got a python script that writes four JSON files (a handful of key, value pairs) with every execution. This script executes around 100k times a day, producing 400k files every day. Every execution produces four JSON files inside a dated directory with a counter, for example:

- /30/04/2021/run1/
- /30/04/2021/run2/
- ...
- /30/04/2021/run100k/
- /01/05/2021/run1/
- /02/05/2021/run2/
- ...
- /31/05/2021/run100k/

I am exposing read API (get_runs) for this wherein people can ask for data within a given date range.

```
def get_runs(from_date, to_date):
   files = []

   # construct file paths for the given date range (from_date, to_date)
   # append file paths to files 

   # call read_files
   return _read_files(files)

def _read_files(files):
   import json
   data = []
   for file in files:
      with open(file) as f:
          data.append(json.load(f))
   return data
```

If you notice, inside the get_runs API call, I am reading files inside dated directories (in a given range) one by one in a loop but this takes a lot of time to complete. Any suggestions on how to optimize this? I want this to be super fast - Note that I cannot store these JSON objects in the database.

Comment: why not build files according to date and store every execution details inside the day log file as a dictionary. should be a whole lot faster.

Comment: `//` is not a python comment ... what did you try to speed it up? is order of the files in the returned data list important? could you parallelize it? Is IO-reading a bottleneck already? is creating the python objects from JSON (aka the "json.load(f)") a bottleneck? did you measure anything?  You create files every 0.8 or so seconds - so your drive is busy writing a lot - is that a bottleneck? why write every measurement into single file - why not one file per Minute or smth alike - opening/closing/writing file handles takes time ... etc

Comment: I didn't try parallelizing it. Yes, I did profile the application and the bottleneck is with the IO reading.

Comment: Try the third party orjson module instead of the stock json module.

Comment: Maybe also look into using sqlite instead of separate files.